# extract similar terms Solr

Tags: solr

I want to extract from a data set, what all are the similar terms and then query with negation constraint on them. For example.

for a the index set, how can i deduce that Blackberry and Nokia are two similar terms. Or say are 2 similar commodities.

Can this be achieved through solr. ?
This is not synonyms. but similarity constraint I need to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Surely not the exact case you are looking for but you can check out [Solr with Mahout](http://searchhub.org/2010/03/16/integrating-apache-mahout-with-apache-lucene-and-solr-part-i-of-3/).
Mahout provides support for [LDA](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/latent-dirichlet-allocation.html) for topic modeling, which will help you to group topics from your dataset

> A topic model is, roughly, a hierarchical Bayesian model that
>   associates with each document a probability distribution over
>   "topics", which are in turn distributions over words.
>   For instance, a topic in a collection of newswire might include words about "sports",
>   such as "baseball", "home run", "player", and a document about steroid
>   use in baseball might include "sports", "drugs", and "politics". Note
>   that the labels "sports", "drugs", and "politics", are post-hoc labels
>   assigned by a human, and that the algorithm itself only assigns
>   associate words with probabilities. The task of parameter estimation
>   in these models is to learn both what the topics are, and which
>   documents employ them in what proportions.

So if within a dataset if you have documents for Mobiles, you would get a group of terms with blackberry, iphone, mobile and so on.
These may not be similar terms but would relate to the same topic.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply.   But I would try Mahout with solr.  So in a way are you saying that the documents would act as a corpus to the bayesian model. Also do you have any clue, does it provide higher weight to neighboring terms or just fields with association can also be traced by the model. It would help me in submitting the data set.    Thanks for your reply.

Comment: you can model the Solr terms to be phrases (bigrams) or single words which will be used by mahout.